# NestJS Kafka - Check for topics in health check

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafka-consumer-api

I'd like to check if my service is consuming a topic as part of my health check.
I created a custom transport for Kafka:

```
export class KafkaCustomTransport extends ServerKafka {
  get kafkaClient(): Kafka {
    return this.client;
  }
}
```

And now I'd like to inject and access it in my health check module:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HealthCheckService, HttpHealthIndicator, HealthCheck } from '@nestjs/terminus';

@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private http: HttpHealthIndicator,
    private kafkaTransport: KafkaCustomTransport <- Something like this
  ) {}

  @Get()
  @HealthCheck()
  check() {
    return this.health.check([
      () => this.http.pingCheck('nestjs-docs', 'https://docs.nestjs.com'),
      () => this.kafkaTransport.client...........
    ]);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Use AdminClient to describe the cluster or topics, or add a callback into your consumer to know if a record is being processed or not

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, that worked. But I would've hoped to re-use the existing kafka connection to get the admin instance from it instead of creating another kafka connection just for these checks

Comment: You should be able to... You can access `this.client.admin`, in your transport? So wherever `HealthController` constructor is called, you should be able to inject the AdminClient. But yes, AdminClient methods make separate network connections from consumers or producers; there's no way around that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped it in a provider which I can then get with `@Inject`:

```
export const kafkaProvider = {
    provide: "KAFKA",
    useFactory: (): KafkaCustomTransport => {
  
      const kafkaOptions: KafkaOptions["options"] = {};
  
      return new KafkaCustomTransport(options);
    },
    inject: [],
  };
```

In health check:

```
@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private http: HttpHealthIndicator,
    @Inject("KAFKA") private kafkaTransport: KafkaCustomTransport
  ) {}
```